# How to return a "date" from a Google Sheet, and use it in another function?

Tags: date, google-sheets

I am trying to find a **date** in a sheet and it does work, but when I return the **startdate** it does not function correctly.

```
function startdayfinder(NomClient)
    {
      const passageclientsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Client Sheet");
      const numlastrowIS = passageclientsheet.getLastRow()-1;
      const dataIS = passageclientsheet.getRange(2,1,numlastrowIS,3).getValues();
    
      var start;
      dataIS.forEach(function(row,i)
      {
        if (row[0]==NomClient)
        {
          if(row[2]=="oui")
          {
            start = Utilities.formatDate(row[1], "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy");
          }
          else
          {
            Logger.log(start);
            return  start;//(Utilities.formatDate(start, "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy"));
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

And this is how I call this function:

```
var startday = startdayfinder(row[0]) ;
```

Unfortunately, I don't know where it goes wrong because the function returns **null**, but the logger shows that the date has been successfully written into the start variable.

Where did I mess up?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `getDisplayValues()`

```
const dataIS = passageclientsheet.getRange(2,1,numlastrowIS,3).getDisplayValues()
```

assuming that dates are also formatted as dd/MM/yyyy in your sheet

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I tryed it and it does not work. actually the logger does not even choes anything. with getValue(), I have at least the corrct answer shown in the log.

Comment: you can't call the function with `var startday = startdayfinder(row[0]) ;` since row[0] has no value, change for clientName. Share a simplified spreadsheet to go further.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have to call the function like this 
**var startday = startdayfinder(row[0])**
because it is in a loop and it is going through a list.

Actually, When I call the 'startdayfinder', itworks and it find the date that I need. but it retuns **null**, thats why I did this : 
**Logger.log(start);
            return  start;**
 To be sur if the function is working and it does working, but it does not return anything.

Comment: ok, but I don't have global visibility on your project. It might be easier to try to find a solution if you provide a sample spreadsheet illustrating the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example